# windows phone c# Bayes algorithm for image processing

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, naivebayes

am working on windows phone c# and trying to implement Bayes algorithm to compare 2 images and state the percentage of the difference? Any help?

Comment: What work have you done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried frame subtraction. convert the image into matrix (colour or bw, does not matter).
now subtract these two matrices and construct an image from the resultant matrix and the difference is alone shown in the image. you can also use the value of the resultant matrix to determine the percentage of motion in these two frames.